# Optional trailing slash in regex

Tags: regex, trailing-slash

```
https://embed.thatsite.com?id=
https://embed.thatsite.com/?id=
```

Im trying to get the trailing slash as optional before `?id=`

I tried

```
https?:\/\/embed\.([^\/]*)\.com\/\?id=([0-9]+) //works with slash only
https:\/\/embed\.([^\/]*)\.com\?id=([0-9]+) //works without slash
```

So, trailing slash should be optional before `?id=` because `embed.thatsite.com` changes with both url types.Is there any way to make it working.Thankyou

Comment: you can make your `\` optional using `?` https://regex101.com/r/lsqEp6/1

Comment: You're consufing the querystring character `?` with the regex `?` (zero-or-one) - so ya you need both :)

Comment: thankyou guys you are awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your `/` as optional using `?`

```
https?:\/\/embed\.([^\/]*)\.com\/?\?id=([0-9]+)
```

`https?:\/\/embed\.` match `http\\embed.` or `https\\embed.` where `s` is optional `?`

`([^\/]*)`  match everything except `/`

`\.com\/?\?` match `.com` and optional `/` and `?` character

`id=([0-9]+)` match `id=` and capture numeric values as many as possible

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lsqEp6/1)

Comment: thankyou very much also for the regex101 site I dodnt know about that

Comment: @Gazi i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
https?:\/\/embed\.([^\/]*)\.com\/?\?id=([0-9]+)
```

Here, the slash is changed with a `?` modifier, which will match the previous character (`/`) 0 or 1 times.